# Rails: Twitter Bootstrap Buttons when visited get black text color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a rails 3.2 app using Twitter Bootstrap via the gem '**twitter-bootstrap-rails**'.  Additionally the forms are created with the **SimpleForm** gem  For a number of the pages I've used the twitter buttons on the form via

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back, :class => 'btn btn-warning'%>
<%= form.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

The buttons are rendered ok.  The issue is that after you select one of the buttons, which visits the link, on returning to the page the text is stuck on the greyed out version as shown below for the '**back**' button:

[image: twitter buttons]

This causes a problem, especially on the buttons styled with 'btn-primary' as the text is hard to read.  An example of this is below:

[image: edit button]

Wondering what setting needs to change and where.  I expected it should be in the **bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less** file but not sure what setting to try.  Tests on **@linkColorHover** didn't work.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Maybe you have additional css in your application. had the same problem with automatic generated assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss from scaffolding.

Comment: I've got a bunch of generated SASS css files, but they only have comments in them.  Did you have variables in the style sheets that you had generated via scaffolding ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always style the `a.btn` items, to remove the decorations on the pseudo classes such as `:visited`

Comment: This was the solution was to override and remove the pseudo classes as suggested.  So in the app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file I simply added:

Comment: FWIW, I had this problem and just needed to remove the `scaffolds.css.scss` that Rails' scaffold generator had added. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507777/twitter-bootstrap-displays-button-with-greyed-text

Answer (score 10):

The best solution I found for this problem is to remove `scaffolds.css.scss` in the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory as suggested by [@tonymarschall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151535/tonymarschall) above in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can use `button_to` instead of `link_to` in your templates.

Because this creates a new form, if you want to simulate the link behaviour, you need to use the `:method => :get` parameter. You can find more info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a combination of a few of the answers, but simply replace:

```
color: #666;
```

With:

```
color: white;
```

In scaffolds.css.scss

Answer (score 0):

You should use Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to find out which CSS property you'd have to override in bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less.

It's kinda hard to tell by looking at images.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that which gives me the class a.btn.btn-primary. Not sure what to do next with it and was trying to make use of the LESS variables as a way to manage it.

Comment: Giving us a link to see the problem live would help.

Comment: Problem is that it's an internal site - but i'll see if I can extract snippet and post up small app on public site