# Rails link_to changed to button_to and styling using with bootstrap btl class

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to use "button_to" style from bootstrap in one of my view for a show action which has 3 link_to actions as shown below.

```
<%= link_to "Edit Article", edit_article_path(@article), class: "btn btn-default" %>  
<%= link_to "Publish Article", '', id: "publish_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  
<%= link_to "Close Article", '', id: "close_button", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

These links gets displayed as a button in one row next to each other.

But when I change call `link_to` to `button_to` as shown below, 
all three buttons gets displayed on separate lines new code is given below...

```
<%= button_to "Edit Article", edit_article_path(@article), method: :get, class:"btn btn-default" %>  
<%= button_to "Publish Article", '', id: "publish_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  
<%= button_to "Close Article", '', id: "close_button", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

So the question is How to display following changed buttons on the same line (or row)?

Partial view is as follows,

```
<p>
<b>Article Posting date</b>: <%= @article.updated_at %><br />
<b>Article Title</b>: <%= @article.title %><br />
<b>Article content snippet</b>: <%= @article.content %>
</p>

<% if signed_in? %>   
  <%= button_to "Edit Article", edit_article_path(@article), method: :get, class:"btn btn-default" %>  
  <%= button_to "Publish Article", '', id: "publish_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  
  <%= button_to "Close Article", '', id: "close_button", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

Removed 2nd part of the question from the post as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Without knowing the css for the buttons. Try adding the `display:inline` to the css for your buttons.

Q2: How about adding `remote: true` to the button/link render line. Rails js adds ajax events to `link_to` and `button_to` elements that use this, using the http method supplied and the url on the element(which you will have to add).

So your code should look something like:

```
<%= button_to "Publish Article", publish_article_path(@article), id: "publish_button", class: "btn btn-primary", remote: true %>
```

You can hook into the ajax events using:

```
$("#publish_button").on("ajax:success", function(e){
   //blah
});
```

[All remote events here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)

Just a note, its not best practice to use click events for submitting ajax requests and there is no need to with rails.

Comment: First, I' using class: "btn btn-primary" styling from bootstrap. The reason I changed from link_to to button_to because after click the text on the button grayed out as in 'visited link'. That's what started this whole change sequence. Since I'm styling these link_to with class: "btn" I don't want their text treated as links anymore. Secondly there is no route to publish_article_path it's just a update call happens in the JS function. Can you describe a proper Rails way? I want to just update a status flag from the show view of an article and do a auto refresh on the page.

Comment: If your problem was a visited link, they you should have asked that question. Use the css pseudo class `:visited` to style them.

Comment: The way I have described is a proper rails way. Your controller action should just update the status flag. Returning an error code or success code, from which, you can decide what to do to the page in the js.

Comment: @ DickieBoy, Thanks for your response. I'll update my answer after trying your change one more time.

Comment: @ sorry for the confusion about the question. I got answer from another SO thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829808/twitter-bootstrap-buttons-visited-link?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to post the rest of your view, but this solution might work to display your buttons on the same row.  You should really just ask Q1 in a another SO Question.

Reference [Bootstrap's Grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) for best customization.

```
<div> <!-- adding a class="row" might be even better for your alignment -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= link_to "Publish Article", '', id: "publish_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= link_to "Close Article", '', id: "close_button", class: "btn btn-danger" %> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Expriment with the `6`'s.  Columns should add up to 12 or less.  Use `col-md-offset-2` to offset by two columns so you can narrow your buttons, but fill in unused columns.

You can also use the `content_tag` view helper to to wrap these buttons instead of using `<div>` tags.

Comment: Moving buttons into <div> </div> tag with class="row" doesn't change the position.

Comment: More importantly, use the `col-md-<number less than 12>` classes to align them at equal vertical positions.

Comment: More importantly, use the `col-md-<number less than 12>` classes to align them at equal vertical positions.

Answer (score 0):

//whatever.css

```
.btn{
      float:left;
  }
```

After this code put a div:

```html
<%= button_to "Edit Article", edit_article_path(@article), method: :get, class:"btn btn-default" %>  
<%= button_to "Publish Article", '', id: "publish_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  
<%= button_to "Close Article", '', id: "close_button", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<div style="clear:both">
</div>
```