# Twitter-bootstrap buttons with gray text after scaffold generator

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very similar problem as this 
[Twitter bootstrap displays button with greyed text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507777/twitter-bootstrap-displays-button-with-greyed-text)
where I have a Twitter Bootstrap button btn-info with a drop down that after I clicked on a drop down item the text for the button is now grey and only shows as white when I hover over it. It never returns back to normal even if I stop the rails server and retart. If I go to a different browser(say I switch from Firefox to Chrome), the button's text is white but then the problem re-appears as soon as I click on a drop down item.

I believe the problem didn't start until after I ran a scaffold generator except I don't have a Scaffold.css to delete as was suggested was the fix for [Twitter bootstrap displays button with greyed text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507777/twitter-bootstrap-displays-button-with-greyed-text)

Any ideas how to stop mysterious permanent gray color of text for button?

Here's my button html

```
<span class="span3 btn-group">
    <a id="j_button" class="btn btn-info session_button dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Send to J location
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a id='j_dropdown1' href="#">New issue</a></li>
        <li><a id='j_dropdown2' href="#">Add to existing</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

with the only css that I added is

```
.session_button {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're actually using a link.

It only looks like a button because of the added class `btn` and `btn-info` which adds the twitter bootstrap styles. When you click on a link, the browser usually remembers that you already visited that link and shows you the visited state the next time you see it.

You might also want to add css styles to the visited state of the link to change it from being gray.

Assuming you want it to stay white, you can do so by adding the following:

```
.session_button:visited { color:#FFF; }
```

Also check out [CSS selector for visited links](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp).

Comment: Thanks I will look into the link. I'm having difficulty believing this is the problem only because I found an older version of my code(before the scaffolding was done but the button is set up exactly the same i.e. using the link) and the problem doesn't show there. Perhaps scaffolding changed how the link behaves maybe? Looking into it...

Comment: Just checked scaffold.css and the a:visited rule is there, so it's weird you're having problems without the file. Are you sure you don't have it under app/assets/stylesheets? I would suggest checking your other stylesheets or you could always override it.

Comment: Looked everywhere for scaffold.css in entire project and also searched for a:visited text and they are not in my project. Not quite sure where its coming from. Also, I check the css in firebug for that button and I don't see the visited rule. Anyhow, I added this to my css a.btn:visited { color: #fff; } and my button's text is back to being white. Its a fix, just not one I'm very comfortable with. Would have rather found how/where this visited css is medling in but for now it will do. Thanks.